# Algolia / React Native - Finding an object using one of its child fields

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have multiple `event` objects on Algolia and I would like to get all the events whose geolocation is within a radius of 50,000 meters of my current position.

An example of `event` object:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name":"My event",
   "isEnabled":true,
   "address":{
      "id":1,
      "street":"55 Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré",
      "city":"Paris",
      "postalCode":"75008",
      "region":"île de France",
      "department":"Paris",
      "addressAutocomplete":"55 Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré, Paris, France",
      "addressComplement":null,
      "address":"55 Rue du Faubourg Saint-Honoré, 75008, Paris, France",
      "country":"France",
      "created_at":"2021-05-22T09:02:00.000Z",
      "updated_at":"2021-05-25T20:29:34.000Z",
      "_geoloc":{
         "lat": 48.8706298,
         "lng": 2.3169336
      }
   },
   "published_at":"2021-05-22T09:07:40.000Z",
   "created_at":"2021-05-22T09:07:37.000Z",
   "updated_at":"2021-05-22T09:07:40.000Z",
}
```

The problem is that the `_geoloc` field is a child of `address` instead of being at the root of the event object. But I need this field to be an `address` child because it is a relation with the `addresses` collection.

I tried this code:

```
index.search('query', {
      aroundLatLng: '49.35749636653998, 1.0939658',
      aroundRadius: 50000
    }).then(({ hits }) => {
      console.log(hits);
    });
```

It makes sense that my code doesn't work because Algolia is looking for a `_geoloc` field at the root of my `event` object instead of looking for it in `address._geoloc`.

Is it possible with Algolia to obtain all the `events` that have an `address` located within a radius of 50,000 meters of a latitude and longitude passed in parameters?